# Jquery Mobile panel scrolls with content

Tags: android, html, css, jquery-mobile

Using Jquery Mobile, I have a panel div to create a navigation system and set the height of it to be 100% of the browser. If the content exceeds the height of the panel, the css overflow-y property lets the user scroll to see the hidden content. Pretty simple right?

Now here is where I'm getting in to some trouble, while the css overflow-y property works fine on iOS devices, Android is giving me some trouble. While the user is able to scroll the panel to see hidden content, the actual content div (`div data-role="content`) also scrolls. So if I have 10 items that I have to scroll to in the panel, the main content div will also scroll until I reach the end.
[Heres a link to a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pHtxe/1/)

If you view this on a android device you'll see the issue I'm talking about. What I want to know if this is a problem from Android, Jquery, or something else. I'm using Android 4.1, JQM 1.3.2, and Jquery 1.9.1

CSS

```
.ui-panel { overflow-y:scroll; }
```

JS (for setting the height of the panel)

```
$(function(){
  $('.ui-panel').css({'height':($(document).height())+'px'});
  $(window).resize(function(){
    $('.ui-panel').css({'height':($(document).height())+'px'});
  });
});
```

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/pHtxe/2/

Comment: Its works on my computer but when I compile everything and put it on a phone, its doesn't work. I'm starting to thing that this may be an android issue

Comment: Omar, you solution works now on Android. There was an error in the markup on my side that was causing a break in the structure. Please leave an answer so I can mark it as correct

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your contents inside the panel with a div and give it a class i.e. `inside`. Then set `overflow: hidden;` for the panel `#panel_id` or `.ui- panel`. For the inner div, set `overflow-y: scroll;`.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/pHtxe/2/)**

```css
.ui-panel {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inside {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

And now comes JS part. Adjust `.inside` height not the panel.

```
$('.inside').css({
    'height': ($(document).height()) + 'px'
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    $('.inside').css({
        'height': ($(document).height()) + 'px'
    });
});
```

Comment: @IgorKonoplyanko http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746298/jquery-mobile-panel-scrolls-with-content/19125681?noredirect=1#comment28277435_18746298 if you have a question, please post it. You may need other modifications.

Comment: I've made it same as in your code, but it's still scrolling together with page content. overflow-y doesn't help in android. dont know why...