# Enhancing a jQuery Mobile Menu System

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

@Omar has created a cool ios style menu system [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20889575/1771795)

I need a few modifications.

1) When the new submenu slides in, the previous menu should slide out.

2) The new submenu should inherit the same background color as the previous menu

Comment: Omar, i think hes logged in ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to close *open* menu while opening the other one. Inside `click` handler which opens either menu, add the following:

```
$(".ui-sub-panel-open")
    .addClass('ui-sub-panel-close ui-sub-panel-animate')
    .removeClass("ui-sub-panel-open");
```

This will close *open* menu then slide next one; complete code.

```
/* open submenu1 */
$('.sub1').on('click', function () {
    $(".ui-sub-panel-open")
        .addClass('ui-sub-panel-close ui-sub-panel-animate')
        .removeClass("ui-sub-panel-open");
    $('#submenu1')
        .addClass('ui-sub-panel-open ui-sub-panel-animate')
        .removeClass("ui-sub-panel-close");
});

/* open submenu2 */
$('.sub2').on('click', function () {
    $(".ui-sub-panel-open")
        .addClass('ui-sub-panel-close ui-sub-panel-animate')
        .removeClass("ui-sub-panel-open");
    $('#submenu2')
        .addClass('ui-sub-panel-open ui-sub-panel-animate')
        .removeClass("ui-sub-panel-close");
});
```

Regarding `background` color, add any color you want to `ui-sub-panel-open` and another color (if you want) to `ui-sub-panel-close`.

```
.ui-sub-panel-open {
  -moz-transform: translate3d(-17em, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-17em, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-17em, 0, 0);
  background: lightblue;
}

.ui-sub-panel-close {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  background: lightgray;
}
```

And don't forget to remove the below CSS

```
#submenu1 {
  background: color;
}

#submenu2 {
  background: color;
}
```

---

#### Update

To slide closed panel to left, modify `.ui-sub-panel-close` as follows.

```
.ui-sub-panel-close {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-34em, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(-34em, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-34em, 0, 0);
  background: lightgray;
}
```

Then you should return *submenu* to its' original position, by listening to `transitionend` events.

```
$(document).on("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend MSTransitionEnd", "#submenu1, #submenu2", function () {
  var position = $(this).offset().left;
  if (position < 0) {
    $(this).removeClass("ui-sub-panel-close ui-sub-panel-animate");
  }
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/7YjPu/)**

Comment: Thanks again. It's just the direction that is wrong. As the new sub menu slides in from the right, the old one should slide out to the left rather than the right.

Comment: This can be done by changing `transition3d(-34em, 0, 0)` in `ui-sub-panel-close`. But this will require additional JS to return _submenu_ to it's original position.

Comment: same problem, the submenu list item remains visible in front of the new submenu panel

Comment: @totalitarian list item of main panel? If yes, in html, place submenus under any other element in panel.

Comment: Yes just the main panel list items. Can you show me what you mean?

Comment: @totalitarian ill check it on Firefox desktop.

Comment: @totalitarian it looks like a problem in FF with `z-index`. I've fixed it anyway http://jsfiddle.net/7YjPu/4/ add this to `click` listener `$(this).css("z-index","auto");` as in the demo. Main demo is updated.

Comment: The fix works well. Next question (hope you don't mind) if I have many items in the panel. How to make the panel scroll without scrolling the main page? Demo here http://jsfiddle.net/7YjPu/9/

Comment: @totalitarian check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/19125681/1771795 but it wouldn't work properly on Android devices. to scroll page keeping panel fixed, add `data-position-fixed="true"` attribute to panel. read more about it: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/panel-fixed/

Comment: So there is no way to scroll the panel and keep the page fixed on android?

Comment: @totalitarian you'll need to use plugins like iscrollview and iscroll. They use transition to move div up and down.

Comment: @totalitarian you'll get scroll bars on desktop. On mobile devices scroll bars look different. You have consumed your questions for today :P

Comment: No problem Omar. Thanks for all your help today. Very much appreciated!

Comment: @totalitarian your welcome, it's a pleasure. Your question deserves a thumb up :)