# Nested sliding mobile menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to find or write a mobile slider menu similar to the one featured on this site:

http://m.houseoffraser.co.uk/

If you click their menu and then click a sub element, you'll notice that instead of opening below the clicked item, the slider has an internal "slider" which reveals more elements.

I have no idea what this type of sliding menu is called and a lot of Googling has achieved no results.

Can anyone tell me what sort of sliding menu is this called and if I can find a similar plugin or suggestion as to how I can achieve this. Any tip is really helpful.

Thanks

**P.S** I haven't posted any code here because what I currently have isn't like this slider at all so I don't think it will help much.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22593638/enhancing-a-jquery-mobile-menu-system

Comment: @Omar thanks a lot for the answer, can you please post that as the answer and I'll accept that?  Cheers  :)

Comment: You're welcome. I can't post duplicate answers, if you find the posts useful, you can upvote them.